# import test files with Nose from subdirectories

Tags: python, unit-testing, csv, python-3.x, nose

I am to find out how to make nose gather test csv files.It's able to pickup on the test unit files them self recursively but not the .csv inside them. Here is how I have my directory lay out.

**Working**

```
Test_Units
    |___nose.py
    |___test.csv
    |
    |___Test_Unit_1
            |_______Test_unit.py
```

**Non-Working**

```
Test_Units
    |___nose.py
    |
    |___Test_Unit_1
            |_______Test_unit.py
            |_______test.csv
```

It's seems like nose needs that file in it's local path.

here is how nose.py is configured

```
import nose
result = nose.run()
```

A Test Unit looks like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from Quandl_RS_Lib import Quandl_Standard

Quandl_Standard = Quandl_Standard()


class TestQuandl_Standard(TestCase):

  def test_Top_Max(self):
      #Function stuff
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of `Test_unit.py`? The problem is probably there.

Comment: lol, "here is how nose.py is configured" --> it uses all default values.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen  can you provide a answer on how to change the default values?

Comment: @Aidin I have updated the post

Comment: you did not ask how to change configuration so it wouldn't be a valid answer, plus I'd just be restating [the documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#configuration) anyway.

Comment: if you do `try: result = nose.run() ; except SystemExit: print ("OMG THE SYSTEM EXITED BEFORE FINISHING!!!")` do you get the overly emphatic message?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen umm..why does it matter about changing a configuration? If you are done trolling, feel free to point to exact spot in the documentation that state this.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a way to correct this in nose, however I did find a way to fix the issue. I went ahead and told each test function to change to correct directory before test begins, so it would be able to find the correct files (example below).

```
from unittest import TestCase
from Quandl_RS_Lib import Quandl_Standard
import os

Quandl_Standard = Quandl_Standard()


class TestQuandl_Standard(TestCase):

  def test_Top_Max(self):
      os.chdir("/path/to/yourfiles")
      #Function stuff
```